# Convert to array in linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
var parentstl = from parentstyle in DBB.vParentStyles
select new {   parentstyle.name,
               parentstyle.description,
               parentstyle.price,
               parentstyle.categories
           };
```

I want `parentstyle.categories` to convert into `int[]` array.

How can I do that?

Comment: What is parentstyle.categories? Objects or ints?

Comment: What is DBB.vParentStyles? Is it a dataset from Entity Framework? Also what is parentstyle.categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Select` to make projections, like this:

```
var parentstl = from parentstyle in DBB.vParentStyles
select new {
    parentstyle.name,
    parentstyle.description,
    parentstyle.price,
    Categories = parentstyle.categories.ToArray()
 };
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new to C#. Now I want to serialize this data into jason format. Below is my code.

Comment: @user3817564 The code did not show up in the comment. You would be better off asking a separate question for serialization, though - it would help to have more eyes looking at the issue. If you would like to give readers of the new question some additional context, you could reference this question inside the new one.